# How to provide the “Privacy policy link” correctly on EU COOKIE COMPLIANCE module?

Tags: cookies

After this recent update of the module, when I run a Status Report, it warns me that: “Privacy policy link not provided”, but I actually think I did it by filling up the field “Privacy policy link”, am I missing any additional configuration on the module set up (Drupal 8.5.5)?

Note that, despite this warning the message abouts the cookies is displayed on the website and the respective button “MORE INFO” links to a page I created with additional info on the cookie compliance.

Comment: `After this recent update of the module` did you run `yourwebsite.com/update.php?` Have you checked the module's issue queue to see if anyone has reported a similar or identical bug?

Comment: Yes I run updat.php and also checked  the issue queue and there is notthing about this

Comment: What did you exactly enter in that field? I find strange that a module gives a false warning (and not an error), and then uses what you entered, but that depends from the code that module is using.

Comment: I checked the code of that module. The only warning it could give when you watch the _Status report_ page is _Your privacy policy link is pointing at the front page. This is the default value after installation, and unless your privacy policy is actually posted at the front page, you will need to create a separate page for the privacy policy and link to that page._ That is true for the 7.x-1, 7.x-2, and 8.x-1 branches.

Comment: That's what I did. I inputted:    /condicoes-de-utilizacao     and although it works the warning remains there on the status report.

Comment: Are you sure that  /condicoes-de-utilizacao is not set as Drupal front page, or it's a path alias for the front page or for /?

Comment: Just to eventually give an answer that is more specific for your case, which version are you using, 7.x-1, 7.x-2, or 8.x-1?

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I'm using 8.x-1.2 Module version, on a Drupal 8.5.5 Instalation. On the Basic site settings, my Default front page filed in filled with   /node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not being able solve the issue I decided to restore my Drupal Site and install first the Google Analytics Module update and after the UE Cookie Compliance Module update and the warning message didn’t appear this time. Maybe just Drupaluck (nevertheless I decided to share my experiance).

A special thanks to all that tried to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's better you'd report issues like that on drupal.org and not here on Drupal Answers.

The recent EU Cookie Compliance updates happened in a rush when during the ongoing development a security hole was found. Because of that a lot of half-ready new features got released.

It happens I just released a patch which may be related to your problem, see https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance/issues/2985543.

But you may not necessarily need the patch. All you need to do is to update to the latest version, then go to the module's config page and choose a method (default, opt_in etc.). Choose *default* to turn back to the initial method before the most recent updates added additional methods.

If that doesn't work try to follow the steps from https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance/issues/2985613#comment-12685609 which was a fix for the 7.x branch but may apply for D8 as well.

---

Last but not least, double-check that the link you provided either goes to an *existing* internal route or is an external link.